# Wireshark rpm packaging - setting the release number

Tags: makefile, wireshark, configure, autoconf

I'm running the configure.ac on RHEL 7.2, I'm wondering if there's a way to set the Release number (which is defined om the spec file) as a variable like the Version number which is being generated by the configure.ac and it's written to the config.h file , I'd like to set a kind of BUILD_NUMBER variable somewhere, and it'll take the value of the exported variable during the execution.

Comment: I thought wireshark switched to cmake years ago.  Have they changed back to using autoconf, or are you using an ancient wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

The release number for an RPM package is set by the `Release:` tag in the spec-file.  Some spec-files are generated, e.g., using autoconf to substitute values such as the release number in a template, e.g., mypackage.spec.in, to obtain mypackage.spec

A quick check of wireshark's source shows that it uses this scheme, but its template hardcodes the release number as `1`.  You *could* modify the configure script and template to add your own option.

For example, adapting the style of `--with-XXX` options used in the wireshark 2.0.1 `configure.ac`, you would add a chunk like this (untested):

```
AC_ARG_WITH([release],
AC_HELP_STRING( [--with-release=@<:@1/no/4/5@:>@],
      [set release-number in package @<:@default=1@:>@]),
       with_release="$withval", with_release="unspecified")
case "x$with_release" in
x[[1-9]]*)
    RELEASE="$with_release"
    ;;
*)
    AC_MSG_ERROR(release is not a number: $with_release)
    ;;
esac
AC_SUBST(RELEASE)
```

and use the `RELEASE` variable in `packaging/rpm/SPECS/wireshark.spec.in`, as you see the `VERSION` value used:

```
Release:        @RELEASE@
```

Alternatively, if you are using the wireshark source without modifying it directly, your build script could

- unpack the sources,
- update the spec-file,
- repack the tarball,
- deploy the updated tarball to your build area

Either way, you would have to do some work.

Comment: I'm not an expert in rpm packaging , what is the best practice of release management rather than hard coded ? If you'll take a look at the wireshark.spec.in , there's a @version@ variable , which is being updated  by the configure.ac , is there any good way to do the same thing with the Release (E.G best practices) ?

Comment: Is it possible to define a default value for `RELEASE`, in case the user hasn't executed the `configure.ac` with the argument?

Comment: Running automake generates/runs the configure script, which generates the wireshark.spec file from wireshark.spec.in; the configure script supplies the default value, which I gave as `1` (one).

Comment: The expression in the `use case` is not working for all numbers, just for digits `1-9`, I've tried a simple `if` with a regex: `re='^[0-9]+$'` and it's not working as well, I'm running the `./autogen.sh` prior to the `./configure`. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: I forgot a wildcard - should be closer now I didn't use a regex because the configure script is supposed to be POSIX.  (You can make whatever change you want locally, but upstream developers are unlikely to accept changes using non-POSIX features in configure scripts).